# How to get updated Lead data in Journey builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, journeybuilder, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

We have created a Journey in Marketing cloud and Lead enter in the journey based on some criteria so after this someone will change the Lead status like Open to Contracted so we need this updated value Contracted in Journey builder in decision split to send some email-based on the updated status.

I am getting the old value that is open in the decision split every time so how I can get this new value in Journey builder after record enters inside the Journey builder.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Contact Data in Decision Split, not Journey Data:

> Journey data preserves the state of a contact's data at the moment an
>   entry event fires, facilitating the use of that data throughout a
>   journey. Contact data captures the data values in the event source
>   data extension at the time when Journey Builder evaluates it. Both are
>   uniquely useful in journey creation.

Read more here: Journey and Contact Data: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_contact_data.htm&type=5

Journey and Contact Data in Decision Splits: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_contact_data_decision_splits.htm&type=5

Comment: Yes, I have checked the contact data but there is no such field Lead Status.

Comment: you need to first set it up in Data Designer, for example: create an automation that will query your Salesforce Data into another Shared Data extension, and in Data Designer, create a new attribute group. It will then become available in Decision Splits: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_create_an_attribute_group.htm&type=5

Comment: There is no such button In Data Designer, click Create Attribute Group

Comment: @RavikantKedia ask your admin to check your permissions